# Create CGI spider animation

Tags: animation

Where would I start if I would like to have a spider animation that I can put over a video of a person sleeping and have the spider crawl out of their mouth.

I tried looking into Blender but that seems more for 3D models and less about animations.

Answer (score 1):

No, Blender does animation as well. Here's an example of a spider animated with it:

However rigging and animating a realistic octopod is not exactly the kind of project you'd start with as a newbie. There's a lot to learn.

But if you want to have a go, you could start with this tutorial on rigging a spider's leg in Blender:
https://www.blendernation.com/2011/03/16/how-to-rig-a-spider-leg-in-blender-2-5-tutorial/